# Enable a checkbox on a Lead record

Tags: trigger, leads

I am looking for a way how to enable a checkbox on a Lead record when the Lead Owner is part of a Public Group.

Could someone help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a trigger on Lead to achieve it.

Whenever the owner changes, you will need to query `GroupMember` object to see if this user is linked to a `Group`. For example:

```
// Assume you got your user ids
List<GroupMember> gms = [SELECT Id, UserOrGroupId, GroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId IN :yourUserIdSet];
for (GroupMember gm: gms) {
    if (yourUserIdSet.contains(gm.UserOrGroupId)) {
        // Then this user is in a group and you can check the checkbox
    }
}
```